# How to subtract one row from others in r?

Tags: r

i have a dataframe with many columns and rows, i need to for each column subtract
the first row from other rows.

```
C1 C2 C3
3  7   9
4  9   4
7  6  11
9  4   8
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can actually subtract fairly directly, but you need to provide the first row as a `list`:

```
mydf - as.list(mydf[1, ])
#   C1 C2 C3
# 1  0  0  0
# 2  1  2 -5
# 3  4 -1  2
# 4  6 -3 -1

## OR
mydf - c(mydf[1, ])
```

Answer (score 2):

We can replicate the first row to create the lengths same and then do the difference.

```
 df1-df1[1,][col(df1)]
 #  C1 C2 C3
 #1  0  0  0
 #2  1  2 -5
 #3  4 -1  2
 #4  6 -3 -1
```

Or another option is transposing (`t`) the dataset, get the difference and transpose it again, which may be less efficient

```
t(t(df1)- unlist(df1[1,]))
#     C1 C2 C3
#[1,]  0  0  0
#[2,]  1  2 -5
#[3,]  4 -1  2
#[4,]  6 -3 -1
```

Comment: Here's a +1, but this is actually overkill as far as I can tell. Just supply the first row as a `list` instead....

Comment: @AnandaMahto You are right.  I didn't think about the `list` approach.